# NumPy use plain-old python list or np.array in Fancy Indexing?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to understand numpy fancy indexing. I still cannot differentiate the usage between `np.array(...)` and plain-old python list `[...]` passing into the (only) square-brackets of `arr` where `arr` is a `np.array`. Here is the concrete example I'm using to learn by doing:

```py
import numpy as np
print("version: %s" % np.__version__) # this prints 1.22.3

x = np.arange(10)
print(x)
print([x[3], x[7], x[2]])
print("---- x[ind_1d], ind_1d=[3,7,2]")
ind_1d = np.array([3, 7, 2])
ind_1d = [3, 7, 2]
print(x[ind_1d])
print("---- x[ind_2d], ind_2d=[[3,7],[4,5]]")
ind_2d = np.array([[3, 7], [4, 5]])
# ind_2d = [[3, 7], [4, 5]]
print(x[ind_2d], end="\n\n")
```

This program can run without any error/warning that I will mention below. But if I uncomment the line `# ind_2d = [[3, 7], [4, 5]]` then I will get a warning:

```
FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is
 deprecated; use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`. In the future this will be
 interpreted as an array index, `arr[np.array(seq)]`, which will result either in an 
error or a different result.
```

and an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../index.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(x[ind_2d], end="\n\n")
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed
```

---

**update**: what I've tried:

- If I set `ind_2d = [3,7],[4,5]`, so I'm changing `list` to `tuple` I still got the error.
- If I set `ind_2d = [[3,7],[4,5]],`, so I'm adding an extra-layer tuple, then the program run without any error and warning.

---

Can anyone provide some rules to follow I can avoid these kinds of errors and/or warnings?

Comment: it probably means literally use a tuple `()` instead of a list `[]`

Comment: What were you expecting that to do?  `x` is a one-dimensional array and you're trying to pass two-dimensional indices to it.

Comment: @TimRoberts: But the program can run without the warning and error if I keep the commented-out line.

Comment: I guess you'll have to store that in a knowledge base.  There are cases where numpy treats np arrays differently from Python lists.  This happens to be one.  It usually isn't an issue, because when you go numpy, everything becomes an np.array.

Comment: @ti7: But the warning sounds like wrapping a `tuple()` to the `seq`. While what you're saying is _replacing_ `[]` with `()`?

Comment: No,  What THAT"S saying is you can do `array[(3,4)]` to do NORMAL indexing in a 2D array -- picking column 4 in row 3.  That's very different from what  you're attempting here, which is picking specific elements from a 1D array to produce a NEW 2D array.  That only works with an np.array.

Comment: @TimRoberts: "That only works with an np.array" try this line: `print(x[ [[3,7], [4,5]], ], end="\n\n")`, which is what I'm saying about. I add a tuple as wrapper to the seq `[[3,7],[4,5]]`. The program run without any error and warning.

Comment: If I instead do what @ti7's comment: `print(x[([3,7], [4,5])], end="\n\n")` both the error and warning persist. So he's comment doesn't solve anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Whats the difference between \`arr\[tuple(seq)\]\` and \`arr\[seq\]\`? Relating to Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56579536/whats-the-difference-between-arrtupleseq-and-arrseq-relating-to-using)

Comment: @Rainning `((3,7), (4,5))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning is telling us that indexing with a list should be the same as indexing with an array, but there are some legacy cases where it's treated as indexing with a tuple.

1d array:

```
In [1]: x = np.arange(10)
```

For this simple case, indexing with a list and array do the same thing:

```
In [2]: x[[3, 7, 2]]
Out[2]: array([3, 7, 2])
In [3]: x[np.array([3, 7, 2])]
Out[3]: array([3, 7, 2])
```

This is your problem case:

```
In [4]: x[[[3,7],[4,5]]]
<ipython-input-4-c3741544a3c2>:1: FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated; use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`. In the future this will be interpreted as an array index, `arr[np.array(seq)]`, which will result either in an error or a different result.
  x[[[3,7],[4,5]]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [4] in <module>
    x[[[3,7],[4,5]]]
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed
```

But using an equivalent array works, producing a (2,2) array from the 1d:

```
In [5]: x[np.array([[3,7],[4,5]])]
Out[5]: 
array([[3, 7],
       [4, 5]])
```

In [5], it is clear that the indexing array applies to the one-and-only dimension of `x`.

[4] is a problem because in the past, certain lists were interpreted as though they were tuples.  This is a legacy case that developers are trying to cleanup, hence the FutureWarning.

The 'too many indices' error without the FutureWarning:

```
In [6]: x[([3,7],[4,5])]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [6] in <module>
    x[([3,7],[4,5])]
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed
```

Let's try this with a 2d array:

```
In [8]: y = x.reshape(2, 5)
In [9]: y
Out[9]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
```

With a nested array, we get the FutureWarning, but it works the same as though we gave it a tuple of lists:

```
In [10]: y[[[1,0],[2,3]]]
<ipython-input-10-4285e452e4fe>:1: FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated; use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`. In the future this will be interpreted as an array index, `arr[np.array(seq)]`, which will result either in an error or a different result.
  y[[[1,0],[2,3]]]
Out[10]: array([7, 3])

In [11]: y[([1,0],[2,3])]
Out[11]: array([7, 3])
```

[11] is the same as `y[tuple([[1,0],[2,3]])]` as claimed by the warning.  Wrapping the list in `np.array` tries to index just the first dimension, resulting in an error because the 2,3 are too large.

```
In [12]: y[np.array([[1,0],[2,3]])]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [12] in <module>
    y[np.array([[1,0],[2,3]])]
IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2
```

===

Indexing a n-d array with a tuple is the same indexing without the ():

```
In [21]: y[(1, 1)]
Out[21]: 6
In [22]: y[1, 1]
Out[22]: 6
```

Technically, it's the comma that makes the tuple, not the () (though `()` and `(1,)` are also tuples)

Indexing with a list is the same as indexing with an array (usually, except for the legacy cases they are trying clean up):

```
In [23]: y[[1, 1]]
Out[23]: 
array([[5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
In [24]: y[np.array([1, 1])]
Out[24]: 
array([[5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
```

Comment: `The warning is telling us that[...]`: The warning says `FutureWarning: [...]`, so how could I know at which version all python-lists (passed-in) will be interpreted as `numpy.ndarray`?

Comment: I really like your answer, thank you! I'm trying my best to digest it. This topic is so desperately difficult for me, I have spent entire day on it.

Comment: `numpy` indexing is a big topic.  The best reference page is https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html

Comment: I did try to read that page before I post my question here. I understand every word on that page but I don't know what it's talking about, lol. Why they don't add this line `[..] in the past, certain lists were interpreted as though they were tuples.` into the future warning?

Comment: Could you help me check whether my explanation is correct or not? https://stackoverflow.com/a/71496870/5290519